# How to programmaticaly add button in iOS game app swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton

Can someone explain the code for a programatically added button in an iOS game application for swift 3 Xcode 8? All the other threads on this topic we're in single view and didn't work for me. I couldn't figure out how to add buttons to the game app Main.storyboard, so I'm trying to make a programattically added button. This is the code I'm trying to use now but doesn't work:

```
var playAgain = UIButton()
        playAgain.setTitle("Play Again", for: .normal)
        playAgain.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        playAgain.backgroundColor = SKColor.green

        playAgain.layer.borderWidth = 2
        playAgain.layer.cornerRadius = 18

        playAgain.frame = CGRect(x: (self.frame.width)/2, y: (self.frame.height)/2, width: 100, height: 36)
        self.view?.addSubview(playAgain)
```

Why would the buttons in single view be different in game apps? Also, when(and if) this is created, how would I modify the Touches ended method to know when the button was touched?

Comment: Please describe: *"doesn't work"*... Does the button not get added to the view? Does it get added, but not where you want it? Is it just that nothing happens when you tap it? (You're missing `addTarget` code, if that's the case).

Comment: It's not added to the view

Comment: Where in your code are you trying this? In your GameViewController's `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I'm trying it in my custom scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is adding the button to the `.view`, but using the coordinate system of the `SKScene`. So, your button *is* there, just not in view.

Assuming you want the button to be centered on the screen (at least, for now), change the placement to:

```
    playAgain.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 36)
    playAgain.center = (self.view?.center)!
    self.view?.addSubview(playAgain)
```

This will put the button *above* the game scene (z-layer, that is), so you can use normal button tap without needing to deal with `touches`. So, right after you add the button:

```
    self.view?.addSubview(playAgain)
    playAgain.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAgainTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and then elsewhere in your class:

```
    func playAgainTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        print("Play again was Tapped!")
        // take whatever action you want here
    }
```

Comment: Just one problem...when I switch to the scene with the button, the app crashes with the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386....... It compiles fine but crashes, and in the console it says   (11db). I googled this error several times but I couldn't find a case where it applied to this... Any ideas?

Comment: I'd have to see a **lot** more information. I created a new project using the "Game" template, and added your code to `didMove(to view: SKView)`, and it runs fine. Without more info, there is no way to even guess at what might be happening in your app.

Comment: How should I post my file?

Comment: Do you use anything like Dropbox? If not, it looks like Mozilla just launched an easy file-sharing site... https://send.firefox.com

Comment: Well I uploaded it to the clipboard. It's called 'Gameover'

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to create a button programmatically. You can create an empty UIView and override touch method. Also you are able to process touch event on this view and simulate buttons action. I think this is a fastest way for you.